# Discord Java JDA | which reaction was addet

Tags: java, discord-jda

How can I check, which reaction was added to a message? I want to create a command (!roles) with some reaction and if you click on one, you get a role.
I tried like this:

```
if(event.getReactionEmote().emote == ":salt:") {
    Guild guild = event.getGuild();
    guild.addRoleToMember(event.getMember(), guild.getRoleById("*ROLEID*")).queue();
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: You should be using `event.getReactionEmote().emote.equals(":salt:")` the equality operator doesn't work with strings in Java for reasons i wont get into here. Even better: `":salt:".equals(event.getReactionEmote().emote)` which guards against emote being null. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) may be helpful.

Comment: thanks for answering... but the if does not work :/

`if(":salt:".equals(event.getReactionEmote().getEmoji())) {
    System.out.print("test");
}`

but i tested, `event.sendMessage(event.getReactionEmote().getEmoji()).queue();`
and it sends the right emoji in the channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `event.getReactionEmote().getEmoji.equals("EMOTE")` where "EMOTE" equals the emoji you want.

You may use [EmojiTerra](https://emojiterra.com/) to find the correct code for the emoji of your liking. (You can find it at "Emoji - Codes". Use the code for "Java, JavaScript & JSON".)

Example: The correct code for salt is `\uD83E\uDDC2`.